# ESP32 Cannot run simple Bluetooth acceptor example

Tags: bluetooth, esp-idf

I'm trying to run the Classic Bluetooth "acceptor" example:

https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/classic_bt/bt_spp_acceptor

With the same sdkconfig configuration settings as the example

I turn on the bluetooth in the phone. I select the ESP32 device.

Then pop up a window with the pairing number:
[image: Screenshot_20230615_111805_Settings~2]
At the same time this windows pops up, in the terminal i receive the following message:

**W (162921) BT_HCI: hcif conn complete: hdl 0x80, st 0x0**

**W (162940) BT_HCI: hcif link supv_to changed: hdl 0x80, supv_to 8000**

As soon as I pair the devices in the phone, the authentication is succesfull, but i receive the following message in the terminal:

**W (245220) BT_HCI: hci cmd send: disconnect: hdl 0x80, rsn:0x13**

**W (245296) BT_HCI: hcif disc complete: hdl 0x80, rsn 0x16**

And the connection process stops there. The connection proccess cannot complete.
The serial port callback never reach the state: **ESP_SPP_SRV_OPEN_EVT** (SPP Server connection open)

I think is related with HCI.

[image: unnamed]

I tried with this configuration:
[image: unnamed]

And also tried with HCI instead of PCM

I tested both ESP32 WROOM 32 and ESP32 PICO MINI 02 and their behavior is slightly different

ESP32 WROOM 32 does not even pair

ESP32 PICO MINI 02 pair and disconnect, like the pictures above

Comment: Please, can you run the acceptor example and try to connect from your phone
https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/classic_bt/bt_spp_acceptor

I cannot run a simple Bluetooth acceptor example using 5.1 version of Espressif ESP-IDF. The connection drops after pairing, like the logs shown before.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [error codes](https://www.lisha.ufsc.br/teaching/shi/ine5346-2003-1/work/bluetooth/hci_commands.html#:%7E:text=Other%20End%20Terminated,0x13) looks like ("*Other End Terminated Connection: User Ended Connection*":0x13)

Seems that after the pairing process phone rejects connection, since SPP is not activated. If you run some app e.g. Bluetooth Serial Terminal connection will be established successfully.

[esp32 bluetooth spp acceptor example (video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qt6hw5CxcPs)